# How do I create a login screen?

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

I am new to C#. I need to develop the following screen. I need to call the child form before the parent form is called. After the username and password are checked and valid I want to shift focus to the parent screen.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you having difficulties? http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I am afraid; if you are not looking for a magician instead of developer?

Comment: your screenshots looks good enough for me :) just look at the code how it has been done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

show the "log on" dialog using `form.showDialog`

Link : 
[MSDN form.showDialog documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx)
.

If the form was canceled, disable or close the parent form according to your wishes.

Answer (score 1):

I asume you are working with winforms.

The easiest way is to create a new Log On form and initiate it as a modal dialog form.

something like:

```
LogOn myLog = new LogOn()
myLog.ShowDialog()

if(myLog.IsLoged == false)
 Exit app
```